Vertical alignment by baseline in css grid doesn't work in Firefox and Safari when height is not defined
I need to arrange multiple items with pictures and titles in a row of a grid like this:


The aspect ratio of the pictures is known.
The amount of columns is known.
The grid's width is inherited from its parent, so it can be any value.
The amount of rows is unknown. This is why it is a grid but not a flexbox.
The solution should be HTML- and CSS-only.

I created a grid and aligned elements by the baseline. When everything works as expected in Chrome, it is buggy in Safari and Firefox:

By experimenting with CSS, I found a hack for Safari:
Doesn't work in Safari:
align-items: baseline;
gap: 24px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

Works correctly in Safari:
align-items: baseline;
gap: 24px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc((100% - 24px - 24px - 24px) / 4));

I could not find a solution that works as expected in Firefox.
I found that:

If the height of pictures in cells is defined in pixels, it works correctly in Firefox and Safari without hacks.
If the width of cells is defined in pixels, it works correctly in Firefox.
If pictures are replaced by blocks with aspect-ratio or padding-top, it doesn't change anything.
If the width of cells is defined as 100% it doesn't work in Firefox but looks different:


Here is the the sandbox and the code:


.grid {
  width: 500px;
  gap: 24px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc((100% - 72px) / 4));
  align-items: baseline;
}

.image-like {
  background: green;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid+h2+.grid .image-like {
  background: orange;
}
<h2>Grid with divs and the hardcoded height (correct)</h2>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="image-like" style="height: 130px;"></div>
            </div>
            title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="image-like" style="height: 110px;"></div>
            </div>
            longer title to fix two lines
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="image-like" style="height: 140px;"></div>
            </div>
            short title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="image-like" style="height: 90px;"></div>
            </div>
            longer title to fit multiple lines. Like 3 or smth
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Grid with divs and aspect ratio (incorrect in Firefox and Safari)</h2>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="image-like" style="aspect-ratio: 0.7;"></div>
            </div>
            title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="image-like" style="aspect-ratio: 0.6;"></div>
            </div>
            longer title to fix two lines
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="image-like" style="aspect-ratio: 0.5;"></div>
            </div>
            short title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="image-like" style="aspect-ratio: 0.9;"></div>
            </div>
            longer title to fit multiple lines. Like 3 or smth
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Grid with images (incorrect in Firefox and Safari)</h2>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/Dahl%2C_Michael_-_Queen_Anne_-_NPG_6187.jpg/150px-Dahl%2C_Michael_-_Queen_Anne_-_NPG_6187.jpg" />
            </div>
            title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/King_George_I_by_Sir_Godfrey_Kneller%2C_Bt_%283%29.jpg/150px-King_George_I_by_Sir_Godfrey_Kneller%2C_Bt_%283%29.jpg" />
            </div>
            longer title to fix two lines
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/George_II_by_Thomas_Hudson.jpg/300px-George_II_by_Thomas_Hudson.jpg" />
            </div>
            short title
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Allan_Ramsay_-_King_George_III_in_coronation_robes_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/150px-Allan_Ramsay_-_King_George_III_in_coronation_robes_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg"/>
            </div>
            longer title to fit multiple lines. Like 3 or smth
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




One solution is to use subgrid, and define 2 rows so that the items can share the same row tracks (1 for picture and 1 for title.) With this, you can have the text to align top and image to align end instead of depending on how the browser decide where the baseline is (Not even sure if it is well defined in spec especially when there exists img).
Since you have an additional div wrapper under .item, you need to either have it display:content or make it as an additional layer of subgrid.
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  column-gap: 24px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  align-items: top;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.item {
  display: contents;
}

.item>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item>div>div {
  align-self: end;
}

As shown below:


.grid {
  width: 500px;
  column-gap: 24px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  align-items: top;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.image-like {
  background: green;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid+h2+.grid .image-like {
  background: orange;
}

.item {
  display: contents;
}

.item>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item>div>div {
  align-self: end;
}
<h2>Grid with divs and the hardcoded height (correct)</h2>
  <div class="grid">
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div class="image-like" style="height: 130px;"></div>
              </div>
              title
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div class="image-like" style="height: 110px;"></div>
              </div>
              longer title to fix two lines
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div class="image-like" style="height: 140px;"></div>
              </div>
              short title
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div class="image-like" style="height: 90px;"></div>
              </div>
              longer title to fit multiple lines. Like 3 or smth
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <h2>Grid with divs and aspect ratio (Work in Firefox and Safari)</h2>
  <div class="grid">
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div class="image-like" style="aspect-ratio: 0.7;"></div>
              </div>
              title
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div class="image-like" style="aspect-ratio: 0.6;"></div>
              </div>
              longer title to fix two lines
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div class="image-like" style="aspect-ratio: 0.5;"></div>
              </div>
              short title
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <div class="image-like" style="aspect-ratio: 0.9;"></div>
              </div>
              longer title to fit multiple lines. Like 3 or smth
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <h2>Grid with images (Work in Firefox and Safari)</h2>
  <div class="grid">
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/Dahl%2C_Michael_-_Queen_Anne_-_NPG_6187.jpg/150px-Dahl%2C_Michael_-_Queen_Anne_-_NPG_6187.jpg" />
              </div>
              title
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/King_George_I_by_Sir_Godfrey_Kneller%2C_Bt_%283%29.jpg/150px-King_George_I_by_Sir_Godfrey_Kneller%2C_Bt_%283%29.jpg" />
              </div>
              longer title to fix two lines
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/George_II_by_Thomas_Hudson.jpg/300px-George_II_by_Thomas_Hudson.jpg" />
              </div>
              short title
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
          <div>
              <div>
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Allan_Ramsay_-_King_George_III_in_coronation_robes_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/150px-Allan_Ramsay_-_King_George_III_in_coronation_robes_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg"/>
              </div>
              longer title to fit multiple lines. Like 3 or smth
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>



